Better way of handling many-to-many relations with EF db-first approach in .NET6
I'm having a Request table (EF generated):
public class Request
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AttendeeRequest> AttendeeRequests { get; } = new List<AttendeeRequest>(); 
}

I also have a table for Attendees (EF Generated):
public class Attendee
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AttendeeRequest> AttendeeRequests { get; } = new List<AttendeeRequest>(); 
}

I also have the many-to-many table for them (EF Generated):
public class AttendeeRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RequestId { get; set;}
    public int AttendeeId { get; set; }
}

My task is to insert the request into the database with relation to Attendee.
I create a transaction, I insert the Request into the database, then I insert the attendees into the database, then, for their relation, I do this:
foreach (var attendee in attendees)
{
    var manyToManyRelationRecord = new AttendeeRequest()
    {
        AttendeeId = attendee.Id,
        RequestId = requestToInsert.Id //this is the already inserted request, so it is going to have an ID
    };
     //Save changes code here
}

This works, but its seems so "manual" for me. Can't EF handle this insertion automatically? How would you solve this problem?

if you don´t need any extra information in AttendeeRequest just remove it. EF will automatically fill the values into the db in AttendeeRequest - table.

@decius after a new scaffold, the AttendeeRequest will be back again. My problem is that I don't see how EF fill those values automatically. Thats why I did this kind of "manual" approach.

It is scaffolding the AttendeeRequest Entity, because you have an additional Id column. Usually you have RequestId and AttendeeId only, Then the AttendeeRequest Entity would not be scaffolded. Is it possible  to delete the Id column?

If you would using code first approach this entity would not be necessary, because EF is handling the many-to-many relationship automatically.

Im having a database table for AttendeeRequest, Im pretty sure this is the reason its scaffolding it.
Yes I know, if my granmother was yellow had wheels, she would be a tram. I cant just change the whole project from db first to code first.

I assume you've read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many

You could give EF the explicit join Table Name in OnModelCreating.
This should avoid to manually set the join table ids in your foreach.
Try the following:
public class Request
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; } 
}

public class Attendee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; } 
}

public class AttendeeRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RequestId { get; set;}
    public int AttendeeId { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Attendees )
        .WithMany(e => e.Requests )
        .UsingEntity("AttendeeRequest");
}

But it could still have problems because if the Id in AttendeeRequest. Without the Id you could just use Attendee and Request entities without any other setting or join entity.
The pure EF way would be like this:
public class Request
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; } 
}

public class Attendee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; } 
}

